# json_decode can't parse Gmail API json in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, google-api, gmail-api

Help me please to decode and get `access_token`.
Have already checked 30+ stackoverflow posts about `json_decode`

So first is `Curl`. These params do not affect json response and decoding: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`
Header output shows it is in utf8 response.

2. Checked json online
   [image]

It has no "&" or backslashes

3. `$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);` and then `var_dump($jsonData)`-says that Google returned `boolean`

Here is `dd` result in Laravel:

[image]

The code after `Curl`

```
 .... 
$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
if ($jsonData === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
echo "json data is incorrect";
}

dd(
var_dump($jsonData),// tell me it is "bool(true)", after json end}
'json_decode results:',
json_decode($jsonData),
json_decode($jsonData,1),
json_decode(  ( stripslashes($jsonData) ),1),
json_decode( trim ( stripslashes($jsonData) ),1),
json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $jsonData), 0 ),
json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $jsonData), 1 )
);
```

Also `json_decode( trim($jsonData) );` not helped

Comment: `// tell me it is "bool(true)", after json end` - you have not even decoded anything yet, this is referring to what `curl_exec` actually returned here. You forgot to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true in your cURL request options.

Comment: @CBroe CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - is present

Comment: Show us the full actual (relevant) code then, we are not here to guess.

Comment: Looking closer, I see you have dd(var_dump(...)) so you are dumping *the result of var_dump* which is just going to confuse things. Use one function or the other.

Comment: Sorry, just missed curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
@CBroe was right

Comment: @CBroe please add answer, I will accept it and thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // tell me it is "bool(true)", after json end

You have not even decoded anything yet, this is referring to what `curl_exec` actually returned here.

You forgot to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true in your cURL request options.

Answer (score 5):

If what you have is a boolean, no amount of decoding will magically recover more data. Your problem is in your curl code - it is not *Google* that is returning a boolean, it is the `curl_exec` function.

That's because by default, curl *displays* the data received, and *returns* true for success.
You need to add this option:

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: yes, just missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could try using the guzzle library or I think the Laravel has a HTTP client built in.

https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $this->client->get(self::API_ENDPOINT);

$contents = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

echo $contents->value->thing;
```